# Is it possible to add registrations to an Autofac LifetimeScope after it was created?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, lifetime-scoping

I know that you can add registrations to a `LifetimeScope` *when* it is created like this:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>  
    {  builder.RegisterType<Override>().As<IService>();
       builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();
    }))
{
  // The additional registrations will be available
  // only in this lifetime scope.
}
```

Is it possible to add registrations *after* the `LifetimeScope` is created? (to add registrations inside the `using` block for example)

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `ComponentRegistry` property of the `ILifetimeScope`, with this object you can register new `IComponentRegistration` which you can create using `RegistrationBuilder` static method :

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForType<ServiceA>()
                                          .As<IService>()
                                          .CreateRegistration();
    scope.ComponentRegistry.Register(registration); 

    scope.Resolve<IService>(); 
}
```